# CSS3 transition opacity for child element

Tags: html, css

I have two elements in the following configuration:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
.parent{
    display: none;
}
.parent .child{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms 4s;
}
.parent.visible{
    display: block;
}
.parent.visible .child{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Now, the code isn't working as I would expect it to. What I would like is when the parent element is shown, or has the `visible` class added to it, I want it to show immediately and then I want the child element to display immediately too. I then want the child to fade out after 4 seconds as the CSS above would suggest but it is not working. Any help?

Comment: You are asking for a transition between two states but not defining how the states would be implemented. How would the parent be shown...you haven't stated the **actual** method (click/hover/something else)?

Comment: I was triggering it with some JS, namely angularjs.

Comment: That would have been useful information for your original question.

Comment: @Paulie_D how exactly? It just adds a class. I didn't have any `:hover` selectors in there because it wasn't to do with hovering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, very interesting.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BpUbx/) is a working Fiddle.

What I have done is to cheat. Instead of using `display:none`, I used `position:absolute;left:-9999px` to "hide" the element, and `position:static` to "show" it.

This allows `transition`s to work as expected.

Furthermore, I've moved the `transition-delay` to the `.visible` class, as this will allow the child to become immediately `opacity:1` when hidden, ready for the next viewing.

Comment: Ick. That's a pretty ugly solution.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, I know.

Comment: More importantly, this will only work once on page load (I think)..We have no idea what would trigger the 'visibility' of the parent.

Comment: Yey! That helped me along the way! I changed it from `position: absolute;left: -9999px` to `visibility: hidden` and `visibility:visible`. This solved my problem though, thank you very much.

Comment: @Paulie_D If you look at my Fiddle, it should work infinitely when you click on the button.

Comment: @DominicSantos Glad I was able to help :)